# getting textbox value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textbox with generated html

```
<input id="datePicker" class="date hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" name="date">

$(document).ready(function () {
        var data = $("#datePicker").val();

        $(".dateBtn").click(function (event) {
            FetchDetails(data);
        })
....
```

Onclick textbox is populated at the page but no value is being sent to the FetchDetails function. What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: you kept value attribute null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are reading the value of the input field at the page load and assigning the value to `data`. Any changes made the in input value will not be reflected in the variable `data`.

The solution is to read the input's value when you need it, so that you can get the up to date value

You need to

```
$(".dateBtn").click(function (event) {
            FetchDetails($("#datePicker").val());
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $(".dateBtn").click(function(event) {
        var data = $("#datePicker").val();
        FetchDetails(data);
    });
});
```

It is better to get the text box value after clicked on the button,Because in your case data will get on the document ready and if we changed further that value then it should be remain same